# retrieve every Php loop variable inside ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The images are stored inside separate folders.

Both the folders and the images are saved in the database. In my gallery page, they are shown from the database in two steps.

1. The folders are retrieved from the db and listed in the gallery page
2. while on-click of a folder, the images are to be listed.
   So far, I have passed the data from the database to the view and i have passed the `foldername`to the `ajax-call` using `onclick` function

and my view code is as follows:

```
 <?php foreach($folder_info as $show){ ?>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" style="font-size: 100px;" aria-hidden="true" onclick="imageslide('<?php echo $show['folder_id'] ?>');" ></a>
 <?php } ?>
```

Presently, I am not able to retrieve the passed `$show['folder_id']` inside the `<script>` 
My ajax call is as follows:-

```
<script>

function imageslide(folderid){
alert(folderid);

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url() ?>/welcome/getall_images",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {'id': folderid},
    success: function(data) {

        alert(data);
    }
}); </script>
```

Comment: Do like this, data : { id: folderid },

Comment: what is the difference b/w 'id' & id..?I tried using it but i did not get it..

Comment: Data should be  `PlainObject` or `String` or `Array`, you have passed wrong format. You can check here [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) @Keynes

Comment: Are you getting folderid inside function imageslide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Ajax Script**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url() ?>/welcome/getall_images",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {id: folderid},
    success: function(data) {

        alert(data);
    }
}); </script>
```

> **Controller Code**

```
function getall_images(){
   $folderId = $this->input->post('id');
}
```